# Page Break Issue On Custom Cheque Page in Odoo 10 Qweb PDF Report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qwebview, qweb

I have faced some of the issue page break in Qweb report in last few days.
I am trying to print my Qweb report for Cheque format and single Qweb page divided into 3 different sections

Section 1 : Displaying invoice list details
 
Section 2 : Bank details and amount which we will pay to our owner/tenant in MICR FONT 13B FONT 
 
Section 3 : Displaying invoice list details

section 1 & 3 are the common and displaying the same invoices details into both of the sections and about the section2 will change as per the 
different amount which we will pay to owner/tenant.

**Expected Result :**

I have 23 invoice details are attached it into single cheque then I want to bifurcate my invoice details into different slot

**sloat 1 :** Display first 10 invoice details into first page
 
**sloat 2 :** Display next 10 invoice details into second page 
**sloat 3 :** Display remaning 3 invoice details into third page

I want to bifurcate my invoice details into different sloat wise page if the total number of invoices are more than 10 lines

**What I have tried from my side ?**

**Attempt 1 :** Using counter variable and update the counter through iterating the loop and break it when 10 is reach divide by 0
Applied this code inside into loping

```
<t t-set="count" t-value="count+1" />
    <t t-if="count%10== 0">
         <div style="page-break-after:auto;"/> 
    </t>
</t>
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
<span t-esc="line_index+1"/> 
<t t-if="line_index+1%10 ==0"> 
    <div style="page-break-inside:auto !important;"> 
</t>
```

Comment: I think you should do this `(line_index+1) % 10 == 0`

Comment: I tried it but still not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also fixed the issue from my end after tried a lot more attempts.

If any one will face the same issue in your future development
so that they can also able to fix it quickly.

### Create a method into specific model  : (cheque.cheque model)

```
def get_invoice_details(self, invoice_ids,cheque):
    vals,container,result,val=[],[],[],1
    invoice_no=''
    for line in invoice_ids:
        desc=''
        if line.is_vendor:
            invoice_no=line.vendor_reference
        else:
            invoice_no=line.number

        pay_amt=line.payment_ids.filtered(lambda m: m.cheque_issued_id.id ==cheque.id).amount or 0.00
        for l in line.invoice_line_ids:
            desc+=str(l.product_id.default_code)+',' or ''
        vals.append({
            'date':str(line.date_invoice),
            'invoice_no':invoice_no,
            'inv_amt':str(line.amount_total),
            'description':desc,
            'pay_amt':float(pay_amt)
        })
        invoice_no=''
    for l in vals:
        if val<=len(vals):
            container.append(l)
        if val % 9 == 0:
            result.append({'section':9,'vals':container})
            container=[]
        val+=1
    if container:
        result.append({'section':4,'vals':container})
    return result
```

In this method I have set section key with its value into result of list for dictionary 
where we are using the same section to making the page break perfectly

### Call the same method and iterate it into Qweb Template

```
<t t-foreach="o.get_invoice_details(o.invoice_ids,o)" t-as="line" >
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <table style="width:100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Invoice Date</th>
                                            <th>Invoice # </th>
                                            <th>Invoice Amt</th>
                                            <th>Description  </th>
                                            <th style="text-align:right">Payment Amt</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <t t-foreach="line.get('vals')" t-as="inv">
                                    <tbody class="sale_tbody">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span t-esc="inv.get('date')" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>                                                
                                                <span t-esc="inv.get('invoice_no')" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span t-esc="o.decimal_formated_amount(float(inv.get('inv_amt',0.00)))" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <span t-esc="inv.get('description')" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="text-align:right">
                                                <span t-esc="o.decimal_formated_amount2(float(inv.get('pay_amt',0.00)))" />                                             

                                       </td>
                                        </tr>               
                                    </tbody>
                                    </t>
                                </table>
                        </div>
                      <span t-if="line.get('section') % 9 == 0" style="page-break-after: always;">
                      </span>
                </div>
```

As per the business logic of get_invoice_details() method 
which is return the data in list form and then we can user the same and render it into the XML template.

Odoo will manage the page break automatically when the condition will satisfy over the XML template
system will automatically bifurcate the page according to source code

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a little bit more of the context and info, perhaps the problem is other than that one are you exposing.

have you tried using a custom python report?

```
class IncrementReports(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.your_model.your_report_name'

    @api.model
    def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name(
            'your_model.your_report_name')
        docs = []
        objects = self.env[report.model].browse(docids)            
        for o in objects:              

            docs.append({...})

        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': docids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': objects,
            'custom_docs': docs,
            'datetime': datetime.datetime,
        }
        return report_obj.render('your_model.your_report_name', docargs)
```

Using a custom report you can create a function to divide the 3 blocks of information, sending this in different variable inside de docargs and iterating over them without check the condition in the XML report.

I don't know if I'm clear, my English is not good enough.